# VisualSVN undelete with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Using TortoiseSVN against VisualSVN I delete a source file that I should not have deleted. Now this isn't a train smash because I can get the file back from the daily backup. However I would like to undelete it from SVN (VisualSVN) so that I can get the history back. However I can't work out how to do that.

Anybody know how to undelete a file from VisualSVN either using the VisualSVN interface or the latest version of TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you have to do is the following:

1. Right click on the folder where you think it is.
2. Choose Show Log under TortioseSVN
3. Find the checkin that the file was deleted in
4. Go down the list and find the file
5. Select Revert changes for this version to undelete.

Answer (score 1):

Did you only delete it locally, or did you commit the deletion? In the latter case, try checking out the previous revision.